# Логика выполнения

Tags: python, django

Всем, привет! Получаю данные через методом GET около 30 элементов в словаре, потом эти данные передаю 
api приложению. Запускаю api со всеми параметрами которые приходят через GET. Вопрос как упростить выражение чтобы в ручную не записывать параметры вида:

```
api -user_id request.GET.get('user_id','') -full_name request.GET.get('full_name','')
и таких 30 значений.
```

Есть пару и лишних словарей в GET, но основном все данные передаю api.

Answer (score 2):

Может так, сначала сформировать запрос к api в строке:

```
api_call = 'api %s' % ' '.join(map(lambda key, value: '-%s %s' % (key, value), request.GET.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте после получения данных сформировать словарь и передать его в API:

api -data {'user_id': '1','full_name': 'Full User Name', 'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}}